# [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so' : file not found [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Tags: odbc

Hi when I run the command: **sudo isql -v "SELFLOOP" admin admin**
I get the following error:

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so' :file not found [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Here are some settings:
**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[SELFLOOP]
Description = ODBC Driver for Linux
Driver = Client
Server = 127.0.0.1
Database = unixodbc
Port = 10314
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[Client]
Description=ODBC Driver for Linux
Driver=/usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

Here are some others info:
**ldd -v /usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff43b95000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f99d5b30000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f99d58ab000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f99d5695000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f99d5303000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033d9000000)

Version information:
/usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so:
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libm.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:
    libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libm.so.6
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libm.so.6:
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1:
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libc.so.6:
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

**echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

```
:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib/bizc/
```

**I have tried everything but I am not able to decipher this error.**

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.THANKS!**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've got a 32 bit isql and unixODBC and you are attempting to use a 64 bit driver. What does the file command say for isql for instance (all components in the chain need to be the same). You could always try running under strace to see what system calls are failing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am sorry to answer late!file isql
isql: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped!file /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
file /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But does file /usr/local/lib/bizc/libBBCpi.so also say elf64 (I'm guessing it will given the ldd output). Your probably going to have to resort to running strace on an isql command to see what is failing.

Comment: i have straced.Do you have Mail.Thanks!

Comment: you can mail it to mjevans@cpan.org.

Comment: HI bohica I have sent the log to you.Thanks!

Comment: I've looked at your log and I'm afraid I cannot see what is going wrong. Your driver file is opened successfully and then closed immediately. I still think it sounds like an elf mismatch issue but there is no evidence.

Comment: Try posting this problem to the unixodbc mailing list. You can find it at www.unixodbc.org.